# Passing string and int in URL

Tags: php, html, url

I think this isnt a very typical question but i am stuck here. 
I have to pass a String and an Integer in an URL for my PHP to process it.

I am building the link like...
`$link = 'index.php?NAME=' . $name . '&id=' . $id;`

but when it occurs in URL, its gets changed to
`index.php?NAME=hello&amp;id=10`

and now id isnt being recognised by GET.

Comment: Fix the routine that outputs the URL.

Comment: Can you show us how you are outputting this link, and in what context you are using it?

Comment: @Adi, the only way for `&amp;` is if you are encoding it for HTML or XML.  It seems to me that you are encoding it, and then using that encoding output in cURL or something.  This doesn't make much sense.  You should build the URL as I have suggested to you, and use it directly.  In any case, show some more code so we can actually help you.

Comment: already tried using `http_build_query(array())` and `urlencode`. Problem Persists the same.

Comment: Voting to close... question is incomplete and no additional information has been posted.

Answer (score 6):

Use `url_encode()` for all of your variables.  Or, better yet, use `http_build_query()`.

```
$link = 'index.php?' . http_build_query(array(
    'NAME' => $name,
    'id' => $id
));
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: It looks like his generating isn't the problem, but outputting it, although I'd generate it like this, too.

Comment: The method looks correct, but my problem still persists. I am using one string and one integer and using a function to generate links. Please can u predict some other mistake?

Comment: `public static function ToSearchResults($searchString, $sCategory) { $link = 'index.php?SearchResults=' . $searchString . '&sCategory=' . $sCategory; return self::Build($link); }`
FOLLOWED BY -
`header('Location: ' .Link::ToSearchResults($this -> search_string_copy, $this -> selected_category));`
Next I am using

Comment: @Adi, What you posted doesn't even include the necessary information to help you.  Sorry, but until you post your code (by editing your original post, not jamming it all into a comments box), I don't know how to help you.  How are we supposed to know what's in `self::Build()`?  Or, `$this->search_string_copy`?  Or `$this->selected_category`?  Break this down to a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/<?php echo $link;?>">Link</a>` should work, can you elaborate how you're showing the link?

Comment: `public static function ToSearchResults($searchString, $sCategory)
{
$link = 'index.php?SearchResults=' . $searchString . '&sCategory=' . $sCategory;
return self::Build($link);
}`

Comment: What does the Build method look like, add it to your question

Comment: You must use `htmlspecialchars()` or equivalent if you are echoing something directly into HTML.

Comment: Please check my comment on the post above.

Answer (score -1):

try this simple solution;

```
$link = 'index.php?NAME="{$name}&id={$id}"';
```

Comment: actually.. I am generating the link in a function and then adding it to an image in the html. Using smarty templating engine.